# Jumping animation

Tags: c#, xna

stayI need to make an animation while my sprite is jumping. I tried to load an animation if a key is pressed but it doesn't function. I jump by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> key. All others animations function.  So, my problem is to load an animation by pressing a key. I think I could use `GameTime.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` but I am not sure. I am new anyway and it is my first game.

```
class Player
{
    PlayerAnimation animation;
    Animation walk;
    Animation stay;
    Animation jump;;
    public Vector2 position;
    public Vector2 velocity;
    public Rectangle rect;
    public bool jumping = false;
    public int health = 5;
    public Vector2 Position{ get { return position; } }


    public Player() { }

    public void Load(ContentManager Content) {

        walk = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("walk"), 46, 0.1f, true, rect);
        animazioneMinima = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("stay"),37, 0.15f, true, rect);
        jump = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("jump"), 51, 0.1f, true , rect);


    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        position += velocity;
        rect = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, 43, 46);
        Input(gameTime);



        if (velocity.X != 0)
            PlayerAnimation.PlayAnimation(walk);

        else if (velocity.X == 0)
            PlayerAnimation.PlayAnimation(stay;
        if (velocity.Y < 10)
            velocity.Y += 0.4f;
    }


    private void Input(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            velocity.X = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 3;
        else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            velocity.X = -(float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 3;
        else velocity.X = 0f;


        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && jumping == false)
        {
            position.Y -= 5f;
            velocity.Y = -9f;
            jumping = true;
        }

    }


    public void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        SpriteEffects rotate = SpriteEffects.None;

        if (velocity.X >= 0)
            rotate = SpriteEffects.None;
        else if (velocity.X < 0)
            rotate = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;

        PlayerAnimation.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch, position, rotate);
    }
  }
}
```

what should i make? :D

Comment: Why not just inserting another `if` statement in the `Update()` method like `if(jumping)PlayerAnimation.PlayAnimation(jump);`?

Comment: It doen't function bro! :( if I do it, it'll load only 1 image of entire walk's sheet.. idk why

Comment: What does `PlayerAnimation.PlayAnimation` do anyway? Does it affect the draw call? Certainly, you have inserted the `if` statement ahead of the other statements and changed the first `if` to `else if`. Otherwise the animation will be overridden.

Comment: The animations function! Player.Animation.PlayAnimation(walk) makes the animation of the walk.. if the velocity is no 0. There is a class of the animation!

Comment: Please add the changed code.

Comment: I just need to call a method for few seconds.. 3 for example.. then i will fix that!

Comment: In this case just declare a `TimeSpan timer` of 3 seconds and call only the jump animation while `timer > TimeSpan.Zero`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how your code works, but maybe yau can write something like:

```
if (velocity.Y != 0)
{ 
PlayerAnimation.PlayAnimation(jump); 
velocity.Y -= 0.05f
}
```

and insted of:

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && jumping == false)`
```

you can write:

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && velocity.Y == 0)
```

then you can skip using the jump bool completely.